# Why does ANSI encode csv lead to issues but not Latin-1 encoded ones?

Tags: csv, encoding, mailmerge

I am reading a database record and write it into a csv file.

- Where `;` is the delimiter and `CRLF` the row ending
- And all values are eclosed with: `"` value `"`
- And every `"` in the value gets escaped with `\"`
- where the escape character `\` in vba is `"`

  `cell = <A:"Hello B">`

  `cell = "<A:""Hello B"">"`

  `row = <"<A:""Hello B"">" ; "<B:""Hello A"">"CRLF>`

Now a value can contain all kind of quotes like

- rigth double quotation marks `”`
- and left double quotationmarks `“`

which leads to missbehaviour If I open the file in word's *merge mail*.

However If I open the *csv* file in *excel* it is working as *expected*.

The vba code for openening the file is

`ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource filePath`

### It seems to be a problem with the encoding

so my question should be how to encode a string into e.g. ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1)

### It is a problem with the encoding

when the table in mysql is

- WIN 1252 (ANSI) encoded the merge mail loads the csv wrongly
- ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1) encoded the merge mail loads the csv correctly

Any solutions to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Today, I solved a problem with umlaut characters in MailMerge in Microsoft Access. Maybe my solution fits your problem as well. "objWordDoc.TextEncoding = 1250" did the magic.

```
Set objWordDoc = objWord.Documents.Add(MergeDocumentFilename)
With objWordDoc.MailMerge
    .OpenDataSource name:=CSVFileName
    .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
    objWordDoc.TextEncoding = 1250
End With
```